# Missing Database Table Cakephp

Tags: mysql, cakephp, permissions

**Error:  Database table users for model User was not found.**

I'm expriencing the error show above and I'm unsure why this is happening. I've searched for a possible solution to this problem and the most prevalent solution is... going to the app/tmp/cache directory and removing the files in the model and persistent folders. I've done that and I'm still seeing this error message. I presume the database is connected properly because I'm not seeing any connection errors and when I use the wrong login credentials, I see connection error messages. I also have a users table so the table does exist in the database. Could it be my permissions? If so how do change them as I'm using Bluehost for my hosting. Please help me with this problem.

Comment: is it safe to assume there actually is a table called users, which has the fields id, username, and password?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click **MySql Database Wizard** in Bluehost to grant users permission duh!!